# MediaPlayer not showing in Layout PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a media with mp4 format. I am trying to put this video in `self.ui.videoPlayerWidget` widget. I can hear the voice of video but video not showing in the window.

I created QVBoxLayout and add videoWidget in this layout with this command:

```
  vbox = QVBoxLayout()
  vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

  vbox.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
```

After the VideoOutput line I add this layout to my video vidget from the ui:

```
    self.ui.videoPlayerWidget.setLayout(vbox) #video not showing in there
```

But it does not work.
When I use         `self.setCentralWidget(self.videoWidget)` instead of     self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget) I can see video, but I dont want this.

Where is my fault ?

Source Code
main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtMultimediaWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QComboBox,QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTransform
import sys
from ScanCodeMedia import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        movie_file = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('./galaxy_background.mp4')
        vid_media = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(movie_file)
        # create video widget
        self.videoWidget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
        # self.videoWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)


        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        vbox.addWidget(self.videoWidget)


        # create media player object   (video widget goes in media player)
        self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None,
                                                     QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)

        self.ui.videoPlayerWidget.setLayout(vbox) #video not showing in there
        # playlist
        self.playlist = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlaylist()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlaylist.Loop)
        self.playlist.addMedia(vid_media)
        # add content to media player
        self.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.mediaPlayer.play()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And Ui_Window file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'media_player_test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: transparent;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.videoPlayerWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.videoPlayerWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.videoPlayerWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.videoPlayerWidget.setObjectName("videoPlayerWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.videoPlayerWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.videoPlayerWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

Comment: include your Ui_MainWindow file.  And Where are you setting the central widget?

Comment: @Alexander I added Ui_Window file. And I set in init function in main.py

Comment: This is what they call an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) please describe what you are trying to do.  You are wasting other peoples time when you change the question after someone gives you an answer

Comment: Use a QGraphicsView, with QGraphicsVideoItem as video output.